# I am failing to run Mule 3 on the command line

Tags: mule

This is what I get on a pristine Mule distribution:

```
$ ./mule
MULE_HOME is set to /home/wena/src/mule-standalone-3.1.2
Running in console (foreground) mode by default, use Ctrl-C to exit...
MULE_HOME is set to /home/wena/src/mule-standalone-3.1.2
Running Mule...
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Launching a JVM...
Starting the Mule Container...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

INFO  2011-07-02 05:00:33,164 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.MuleContainer: 
**********************************************************************
* Mule ESB and Integration Platform                                  *
* Version: 3.1.2 Build: 21975                                        *
* MuleSoft, Inc.                                                     *
* For more information go to http://www.mulesoft.org                 *
*                                                                    *
* Server started: 2011/07/02 5:00 AM                                 *
* JDK: 1.6.0_18 (mixed mode)                                         *
* OS: Linux (2.6.39-2-686-pae, i386)                                 *
* Host: debian (127.0.1.1)                                           *
**********************************************************************
INFO  2011-07-02 05:00:33,247 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ New app 'default'                                        +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ERROR 2011-07-02 05:00:33,250 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy app 'default', see below                +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ERROR 2011-07-02 05:00:33,250 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService: org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy application [default]
INFO  2011-07-02 05:00:33,254 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.StartupSummaryDeploymentListener: 

**********************************************************************
*            - - + APPLICATION + - -            * - - + STATUS + - - *
**********************************************************************
* default                                       * FAILED             *
**********************************************************************

INFO  2011-07-02 05:00:33,279 [WrapperListener_start_runner] org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentService: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Mule is up and kicking (every 5000ms)                    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I am however able to run Mule from Eclipse.

Note that a recent development snapshot leading to **3.2** release didn't have any such problem.

Comment: Is this a fresh install or have you done some deploys in it?

Also what is the content of your apps directory?

Comment: And also what is in ../logs/mule-app-default.log ?

Comment: It's a pristine install and the log, named "logs/mule.og", has the same info as in the attached message. There is no other log (according to `hg status`).

Comment: Mmmh, puzzling... Does the user you use to start have permission to write in the apps directory?

Comment: Thanks much for that suggestion. See my answer for the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something weird that Mercurial (Debian's **1.8.3-1+b1** in Unstable) does: whenever I run `hg clean`, even if there is nothing to clean (`hg status` output is null), trying to run `./mule` fails with the stated error.

Solution: stay away from that `clean` command for now.

Comment: What's the relationship between Mercurial and Mule?

Comment: I extracted Mule and made it a Mercurial repository so I could track the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Mule is failing probably because an empty directory (lib/shared/default) is missing.

Hg doesn't version empty directories.